# Javascript errorType Error on line 11: Cannot read property 'oddNum' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to code the following by looping through and output the array with values more than or equal to 2:

```js
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const objToArray = [];
// ADD CODE HERE
for (let i in checkObj) {
  if (checkObj.value[i] >= 2);
  objToArray.push(checkObj.value[i]);
}
console.log(objToArray);

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do. As you have define `checkObj` as an object but want to use as an array

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `checkObj[i]` instead of `checkObj.value[i]` to access your object properties and enclose the body of your `if` statement in braces (or at least remove the semicolon after your `if` statement since it is only followed by a single expression).

```js
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const objToArray = [];
for (let i in checkObj) {
  if (checkObj[i] >= 2) {
    objToArray.push(checkObj[i]);
  }
}
console.log(objToArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to create an array from the object values, then a simple [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const filteredArray = Object.values(checkObj).filter(num => num >= 2);
console.log(filteredArray)
```